# Automatically running tmux in fish

Tags: tmux, fish

I've recently changed my default shell to fish (from bash). I had tmux set up to run automatically whenever I opened the console with bash, but I'm not sure how to set it up with fish.

I tried putting

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux
```

in fish.config, but that didn't work. How do I set tmux to automatically run in fish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux
```

to

```
test $TERM != "screen"; and exec tmux
```

http://fishshell.com/docs/2.1/commands.html#test
http://fishshell.com/docs/2.1/commands.html#and